# Coordinates for multiple countries

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data

I am trying to plot polygons for multiple countries, say `"UnitedStates"` and `"Canada"`. US data is generated thus:

```
coordsUS = CountryData["UnitedStates", "Coordinates"]
```

and Canadian data thus:

```
coordsCanada = CountryData["Canada", "Coordinates"]
```

I want to pass the combination of these two lists into the routines on this page. I cannot figure out how to combine these two lists into a single list of the same structure. The structure is:

```
{{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}}
```

I know how to combine lists of the following form:

```
{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}
```

but the extra depth is confounding me. I try putting the latter into a list thus:

```
l = {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}} 
z = {l}
```

but that does not work. `AppendTo` does not work either.

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

-Tony

Answer (score 7):

If your aim is just to plot Canada and the United States, "SchematicPolygon" may be what you want. You could use:

```
canus = {usa, 
    canada} = {CountryData["UnitedStates", "SchematicPolygon"], 
    CountryData["Canada", "SchematicPolygon"]};
Graphics[canus]
```

[image]

If you want to get the polygon coordinates, and display both (you can use Join):

```
canusp = Join @@ (canus /. Polygon[x__] :> x);
Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Red], Polygon[canusp]}]
```

You can choose whatever styling suits your needs.

Apologies if I have misunderstood your question.
[image]

Comment: @ubqdqn Good answer, but I hope that this isn't our future :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Flatten[ ]` function (first level) on both lists, and combine those results. More specifically,

```
coordsUS = Flatten[CountryData["UnitedStates", "Coordinates"], 1]
```

and

```
coordsCanada = Flatten[CountryData["Canada", "Coordinates"], 1]
```

are in the form that you are familiar with combining. For reference see [Flatten](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html).